# Bind the text field content to Ok button of RadWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik, radwindow

In my application built on MVVM architecture using C# & WPF, I'm using the **RadWindow** to prompt the user to enter the filename with **Ok & Cancel** options.

I want to be able to **enable/disable OR visible/invisible** the OK button on the basis of user input.

**Ex:
Filename entered -> Ok button enabled/visible**

Filename empty -> Ok button disabled/invisible.

How can I acheive this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Telerik `RadPrompt` window has a custom `Template` which contains a `TextBox` and two `Buttons`. To enable or disable the `Button` based on the input of the `TextBox`, you can add a `Binding` to the `IsEnabled` property of the OK `Button`:

```
                    <telerik:RadButton x:Name="OK"
                            Command="{x:Static telerik:WindowCommands.Confirm}"
                            telerikNavigation:RadWindow.ResponseButton="Accept"
                            MinWidth="70"
                            IsTabStop="True"
                            TabIndex="1"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            telerik:LocalizationManager.ResourceKey="Ok"
                            Margin="0 10 8 8"
                            IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=PromptTextBox,Path=Text.Length}" />
```

Comment: Thanks! This was simple. I should have a digged a little more.